# How to get a list of String stored in a Java HashMap as a value

Tags: java, android, kotlin, java-native-interface, jnienv

So, I have a hashmap declared in kotlin as:

```
var hm = hashMapOf("in1" to arrayListOf("a","b","c"))
```

I want the value of "in1" in JNI, for that this is what I'm doing & my app is crashing, can someone help me out?

```
class hashMap = env->GetObjectClass(hm);
jmethodID getID = env->GetMethodID(hashMap, "get", "(Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/String;");
jobjectArray value = (jobjectArray) env->CallObjectMethod(hm,getID,(jstring) "in1");
```

Comment: Use `javap -s` to get the internal method signature of your HashMap. It will probably be `Object get(Object)`

Comment: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo037